# Парсинг txt-файла

Tags: python, файлы, синтаксический-анализ

Всем привет! Есть .txt файл, строки в котором размещены следующим образом (text - везде разный, a и b одинаковые для каждой строки):

```
a "text"  
b "text"  
a "text"  
b "text"  
...
```

Необходимо текст превратить в пары вида:

```
a "text" - b "text"  
a "text" - b "text"
```

Буду рад любому совету: каким образом это сделать, в каком направлении копать и т.д.

Answer (score 4):

Ну на вскидку сделал бы так, если я правильно понял вопрос и если надо в файл сохранять:

```
in_file = "IN.txt"
out_file = "OUT.txt"
data_file = []

# Открыли, прочитали, получили список
with open(in_file, 'r') as read_file:
    for line in read_file:
        data_file.append(line.strip('\n'))

# Соединили из списка в строку, записали построчно
with open(out_file, 'a') as save_file:
    tmp_string = ''
    for num, line in enumerate(data_file):
        if num % 2 == 0:
            tmp_string = line
            continue
        else:
            result = '%s - %s\n' % (tmp_string, line)
            save_file.write(result)
```

Но это если строки идут одна за одной по очередности и никогда не меняются. Т.е. всегда:

```
a "text"
b "text"
```

Результат будет:

```
a "text" - b "text"
a "text" - b "text"
```

**Если есть еще и c "text":**

```
in_file = "IN.txt"
out_file = "OUT.txt"
data_file = []

# Открываем и парсим файл
with open(in_file, 'r') as read_file:
    tmp_string = ''
   # Перебираем файл по строкам и сравниваем начальный символы строки
    for line in read_file:
        my_string = line.strip('\n')
        if my_string[0] == "c":
            data_file.append(my_string)
        if my_string[0] == "a":
            tmp_string = my_string
        if my_string[0] == "b":
            tmp_string = '%s - %s' % (tmp_string, my_string)
            data_file.append(tmp_string)
            tmp_string = ''

# Сохраняем в новом файле
with open(out_file, 'a') as save_file:
    for line in data_file:
        save_file.write('%s\n' % line)
```

Из

```
c "text"
a "text"
b "text"
a "text"
b "text"
c "text"
```

Получим:

```
c "text"
a "text" - b "text"
a "text" - b "text"
c "text"
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! А если иногда будет встречаться третья строка, которую нужно оставить как есть, то есть:

c "text2"

a "text"

b "text"

Превратить в:

c "text2"

a "text" - b "text"

?

Comment: Приведите пример файла пожалуйста. Как примерно есть по-факту. Или у вас так и будет:

с "text2"
a "text"
b "text"

?